# Validate string to ensure it's between a specific range

Tags: php, validation

I've got a range of equipment Ids that exist in a MySQL table that have the following format

```
a01
a02
a03
b01
b03
b04

etc...
```

I'm grabbing this value from a Query string using `$_GET` and then querying the DB.

How would I go about validating it so I ensure that it fits within the range of existing Ids?

Comment: What is the range of the ids?

Comment: Depending on the format of the IDs you probably need to split them and validate the parts of it.

Comment: May some value in the range miss ? May this list be updated ? If yes, a query to the DB seems the simpliest way to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MySQL, you can write the query so that it checks that the given equipment ID is within the equipment IDs in your table.  Since you've written $_GET, I assume you're working in PHP.

I'm assuming that the table you're working with is called "equipment."

```
$equipment_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['equipment_id']);
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(equipment_id) FROM equipment WHERE equipment_id = \''.$equipment_id.'\'';
$result = mysql_query($query);  

$ary = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($ary[0] == '0') { 
    // equipment id not in table.
} else { 
    // equipment id in table.
}
```

You'll notice that I'm using mysql_real_escape_string(...)  - this will escape MySQL special characters, to prevent a malicious individual from submitting SQL that could truncate your call and send a different request.

Here are the docs for mysql real escape string, if you're interested: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php